# add a bin category to a dataframe

Tags: python

I want to add a bin column to my dataframe that indicates teh bin that the row belongs to.

I can see the bins in a histogram, but I want to be able to find the binn for a dataframe or subset of frame.

Ive been trying this with numpy.linespace but its not working as i expect, for one, its rounding is odd, so lets say i expect a boundary to be 1000, linespace gives me 1024. looks like a floating point issue but i cant get it resolved.

Even ignoring this, i have not been able to add the bin to the dataframe. Would appreciate help, based on the below dataset, using bins of size 5.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math
import pyodbc

data = [{ 'uid':1,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':24},
        { 'uid':2,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':np.nan},
        { 'uid':3,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':23},
        { 'uid':4,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':12},
        { 'uid':5,'Region':'oaklahoma', 'metric1':np.nan},
        { 'uid':6,'Region':'oaklahoma', 'metric1':45},
        { 'uid':7,'Region':'oaklahoma', 'metric1':12},
        { 'uid':8,'Region':'oaklahoma', 'metric1':16},
        { 'uid':9,'Region':'oaklahoma', 'metric1':19},
        { 'uid':10,'Region':'oaklahoma', 'metric1':22},
        { 'uid':11,'Region':'oaklahoma', 'metric1':np.nan},
        { 'uid':12,'Region':'oaklahoma', 'metric1':39},
        { 'uid':13,'Region':'oaklahoma', 'metric1':39},
        { 'uid':14,'Region':'alaska', 'metric1':39},
        { 'uid':15,'Region':'alaska', 'metric1':np.nan},
        { 'uid':16,'Region':'alaska', 'metric1':28},
        { 'uid':17,'Region':'alaska', 'metric1':32}
        { 'uid':18,'Region':'alaska', 'metric1':39},
        { 'uid':19,'Region':'kentucky', 'metric1':np.nan},
        { 'uid':20,'Region':'kentucky', 'metric1':28},
        { 'uid':21,'Region':'kentucky', 'metric1':32}
        { 'uid':22,'Region':'kentucky', 'metric1':39},
        { 'uid':23,'Region':'florida', 'metric1':np.nan},
        { 'uid':24,'Region':'florida', 'metric1':28},
        { 'uid':25,'Region':'michigan', 'metric1':32}
        { 'uid':26,'Region':'michigan', 'metric1':23},
        { 'uid':27,'Region':'michigan', 'metric1':np.nan},
        { 'uid':28,'Region':'michigan', 'metric1':23},
        { 'uid':29,'Region':'colorado', 'metric1':14}
        { 'uid':30,'Region':'colorado', 'metric1':45
        { 'uid':31,'Region':'colorado', 'metric1':np.nan},
        { 'uid':32,'Region':'colorado', 'metric1':50},
        { 'uid':33,'Region':'idaho', 'metric1':12}
        { 'uid':34,'Region':'idaho', 'metric1':43},
        { 'uid':35,'Region':'ohio', 'metric1':np.nan},
        { 'uid':36,'Region':'ohio', 'metric1':28},
        { 'uid':37,'Region':'ohio', 'metric1':32}
        ]

testDataset = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to bin your data? Please, show expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [numpy.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html)

For example:

```
testDataset = pd.DataFrame(data)

bin_bounds = np.linspace(0, 1000, 1000/5.)
bins = np.digitize(testDataset.metric1, bin_bounds) # compute bins
testDataset["bin"] = bins # add column to testDataset
print(testDataset)
```

yields:

```
       Region  metric1  uid  bin
0    nebraska     24.0    1    5
1    nebraska      NaN    2  200
2    nebraska     23.0    3    5
3    nebraska     12.0    4    3
4   oaklahoma      NaN    5  200
5   oaklahoma     45.0    6    9
6   oaklahoma     12.0    7    3
7   oaklahoma     16.0    8    4
8   oaklahoma     19.0    9    4
9   oaklahoma     22.0   10    5
```

(I'll let you decide what to do with the NaNs)